# Bake generator animation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

Hi Im using a great generator called Flower Generator (bought from https://blendermarket.com/products/geonodes-flower-gen)

It uses Geometry nodes to grow a plant. It animates the plant via geometry nodes.

How do I bake the animation to GLB or USDZ?
I can get the alembic bake but cant get from that to GLB or other.
Might need to convert to PSR but dont know.

(I want to convert this animation into USDZ for Reality Composer)